# What am i supposed to do with a question of mine if it's no longer valid?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42321/when-i-kill-xserver-it-causes-a-random-process-usually-compiz-to-use-100-of-a) some time ago . After today's reinstallation of ubuntu I no longer face this problem. What am i supposed to do with the question now?

Comment: Best thing you could do would be to post the resolution as an answer, and then accept it. I think you are only allowed to accept your own answer two days after posting it.

Comment: Another way to go about this is just flag it for closure. We'll just say it's too localized since you can no longer reproduce it.

Comment: Answering something along the lines of "i can no longer reproduce it" seemed a little strange to me (and mentioning there that formatting saved the day wouldn't be the best idea), so i flagged it mentioning that i can no longer reproduce it.

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: This question looks like it should just be deleted.

Comment: It won't allow me because it need a day to allow for reopening. If you can bypass it and delete it, go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you flag it for closure as "Too Localized" since you can no longer reproduce the error (yay!) That way others who have the problem won't be waiting on a stale question and can start a new thread.

Comment: If the question is **very** specific and unlikely to affect others, go ahead and 
delete the question altogether. These extremely specific questions, once answered, are litter at best.